# Make hidden div and inputs optional for valid form submit with jquery.validate

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, jquery-validate

I have a form that may only be one page or may be two pages depending on whether it is a single individual or two people applying. What I am doing right now is enabling a link that allows the user to get to the next group of form elements for their co-applicant via an onchange event that shows the link that will slideToggle the first users inputs and show the inputs for the additional users. It's a pretty lengthy form so I cut it down to a few elements so I could fiddle it out:

[Das Fiddle is here](http://jsfiddle.net/TvQFj/)

```
<form method="POST" id="refiLoanForm" action="mailto:i@i.com">
<!--START PRIMARY APPLICANT -->
<div id="primary-applicant">
   <label>
      Application Type
      <select name="applicationType" id="applicationType" class="wider" required>
         <option value="individual">Individual</option>
         <option value="joint">Joint</option>
      </select>
   </label>
   <br>
   <label for="loan-amount" id="loan-amount-label">Requested Finance Amount
   <input type="text" id="loan-amount" name="loanAmount"  required/></label>
   <br>
   <label for="remaining-term">Current Loan Remaining Term
   <input type="text" id="remaining-term" name="remainingTerm" max="3" size="3" required class="override"/>
   </label>
   <br>
   <a href="#" class="primaryApplicantSwitch" id="singleSubmitBtnLink2" style="display: none">CONTINUE TO CO-APPLICANT</a>
</div>
<!--END PRIMARY APPLICANT -->
<!--START CO_APPLICANT -->
<div id="co-applicant" style="display: none">
   <a href="#" id="backToPrimary">Back to Primary Applicant</a>
   <br>
   <label for="co-first-name">First Name
   <input type="text" id="co-first-name" name="coApplicantGivenName" maxlength="32" required/>
   </label>
   <br>
   <label for="co-last-name">Last Name
   <input type="text" id="co-last-name" name="coApplicantFamilyName" maxlength="32" required/>
   </label>
</div>
```

JS:

```
  $('#refiLoanForm').validate({
    onkeyup: false,
    ignore: ":disabled",
    submitHandler: function (form) { // for demo
        alert('valid form');
        return false;
    }
});
$("#singleSubmitBtnLoan").bind('click', function () {
    $('#refiLoanForm').valid();
});
//Handle the content being shown
$("#singleSubmitBtnLink2").on('click', function () {
    $("#primary-applicant").slideToggle("slow");
    $("#co-applicant").slideToggle("slow");
});
$("#backToPrimary").on('click', function () {
    $("#primary-applicant").slideToggle("slow");
    $("#co-applicant").slideToggle("slow");
});
$('#applicationType').on('change', function() {
    if ($(this).val() === 'joint') {
        $('.primaryApplicantSwitch').slideToggle("slow");
        $('.jointApplicantSwitch').slideToggle("slow");
    } else {
        $('.primaryApplicantSwitch').slideToggle("slow");
        $('.jointApplicantSwitch').slideToggle("slow");
    }
});
```

So in theory, the user can enter the fields and hit submit and the form is either valid or throws some errors. Or, the user can add a co-applicant, and validate the form on the link click before toggling to the next group of inputs.

Any ideas on how I would bind all of this to the one button and get it to play nice with jquery.validate?

Comment: It's too lengthy to go through, but I'll give you the last piece. Likely you are only wanting to require certain fields on certain conditions: `required: function(element){ return $(".applicationType").val() =='joint'; }`

Comment: I think I see where you're going with that. I'll start down that path. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot dynamically "toggle" the rules of input fields.

However, you can use [the `.rules()` method](http://jqueryvalidation.org/rules/) to dynamically add/change/remove rules, which essentially mimics the behavior of a toggle.

Also, since you're talking about fields that are hidden, you'll need to disable the option that makes validation ignore all hidden fields.

```
ignore: []
```

Comment: Ok, so if I understand correctly you are saying that all the rules for the second part of the form which may or may not be used depending on the select should start off with no rules so that they are not required to submit the form. But, onchange of the select that would allow the user to get to the hidden elements, then dynamically add the rules and have them added to the elements based on the change being recognized. Also, I have to keep the ignore because there are some fields on the first part of the form that are hidden unless the user selects yet another option.

Comment: Gave you the win cause you pointed me in the right direction. Thanks again Sparky. http://jsfiddle.net/TvQFj/3/  So it sort of works like that but I need to still find a way to have the same button be used either for the single page validation and submit or to validate and then slideToggle to the next group. Guess I can just addend some attributes and tags to the button and form processor on change.

Comment: @isaacweathers, I like doing multi-step forms with completely separate sets of `<form></form>` tags and different instances of `.validate()`.  That way, I don't have to worry about toggling hidden fields.  [Check out some of my old jQuery Validate answers for working examples and jsFiddles](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A594235+%5Bjquery-validate%5D+stepped).

Comment: I had thought about constructing it that way but do to constraints currently existing... it has to be one form. But yeah it would have been easier that way. Thanks for the link to the other fiddles.

Comment: Actually I think I might be close to what I am needing but need to clean up the scripts. Let me know what you think Sparky. http://jsfiddle.net/TvQFj/11/  Seems to be working how I need it to.

Comment: @isaacweathers, don't have time to inspect throughly but you cannot have same option inside `.validate()` listed twice.  You have two instances of the `ignore` option.  One will always take precedence over the other.  It only _appears_ to work because, by default, `:disabled` and `:hidden` elements are always ignored.